# How to create table according to screenshot using html and css

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot]

I have only problem with the small column. How to create the small column.

Comment: Please read [ask] and put a [mcve] in your question

Comment: How can I delete questions ?? it's wired

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough solution, using the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes:

```
<style>
th, td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Description of waste</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="6">List of wastes</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Quantity</th>
    <th colspan="2">The chemical/biological components</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Physical form</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Hazard code(s)</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Container type</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Concentration</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```